# ReactNative iOS app crash due to memory leak

Tags: ios, react-native, memory-leaks, react-native-ios

My ReactNative app crashes due to a memory leak in iPhone 6 while running a release build but works fine within the simulator.
As I'm using gif and many images for which used packages are react-native-fast-image and react-native-cached-image but none of them worked out.

Attached screenshot of leaks tracking 
[image: Memory Leaks Tracking Data]

Comment: And what is the question? :) It doesn't crash in the simulator because it has almost unlimited RAM (limited by your machine RAM actually), also simulators do not send memory warnings.
Your app allocated near 2.5Gb and it's almost impossible on the real device (on iPhone X maybe). So you have to check your code for two things: do you release unnecessary images and are there any memory leaks. Both goals can be achieved by Instruments.

Comment: @dive  memory size increases after fetching products images(which is required).